# Find description in man pages for environment variables shown with env command

Tags: shell, environment-variables, man

In man pages, where can I find a detailed description of the environment variables that are listed when `env` command is run?

I have tried `man env` but it only provides me one example for `TZ` environment variable

Comment: You probably can't find a description of all of them, simply because any application is free to define & use environment variables of its own.  For instance, on my system, there are environment vars that belong to my editor, MPI, CUDA, Java, QT, and more.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

On Linux, [`man 7 environ`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html) describes a number of common environment variables, and gives references to other man pages which describe them in more detail. Equivalents exist on other systems; see for example [the FreeBSD version](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=environ&apropos=0&sektion=7). (Historically, Unix V7 had an equivalent in section 5; the BSDs have had this in section 7 since at least BSD4.3.)

In general, to look through all the man pages which mention a given environment variable, you can use `man -K`, which runs a full-text search in all the installed man pages’ sources, with the `-w` and `-i` options (which respectively list man pages instead of viewing them, and match the strings’ case):

```
man -Kiw TZ
```

Comment: See also Alt+/ in `info` to recursively search info pages from the info directory (Alt+} for next entry).

Comment: Also `info -k ENV_VAR_NAME` to look for that in all info indexes. Or even better: within `info`: `Alt+x index-apropos`